# When is "metric dimension" well defined?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, dimension-theory, matroid-theory

A subset $B$ of a metric space $(M,d)$ is called a **metric generating set** if and only if $$[\forall b \in B,  d(x,b)=d(y,b)] \implies x = y \,. $$ A metric generating set $B$ is called a **metric basis** if it is minimal with respect to inclusion among metric generating sets (in obvious analogy to vector spaces).

> The **metric dimension** of $(M,d)$ is the cardinality of any metric basis.
>
> **Question:** For which metric spaces is metric dimension well-defined? When can we be sure that any metric basis for a metric space has the same cardinality?

Sufficient criteria will suffice for answers, as will necessary criteria, although of course the holy grail of answers would be a non-trivial necessary and sufficient criterion.

**Note:** This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric). There, [the accepted answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275771/93694) pointed out that the notion of metric dimension does not make sense in arbitrary metric spaces.

In a matroid, any basis has the same cardinality, but there are metric spaces with metric generating sets of minimal yet non-equal cardinalities.

Nevertheless, it does seem possible that metric dimension may make sense for certain classes of metric spaces, e.g. Euclidean spaces ([Murphy, *A Metric Basis Characterization of Euclidean Space*, 1975](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102868444)) or graphs ([Ramirez-Cruz, Oellermann, Rodriguez-Velazquez, *The Simultaneous Metric Dimension of Graph Families*, 2015](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00565.pdf)). It is unclear to me what property common to these two types of metric spaces allows the definition to be well-formed/well-defined for them.

In the case of Euclidean spaces, it seems intuitively clear that this notion should be related to that of affine independence, but coordinate-free definitions of affine independence (solely in terms of the metric) are rare (e.g. [section 2.6 here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/geombchap2.pdf)), so I am still working on the algebra to show the connection.

Comment: Murphy imposes a requirement of *convexity*, so I wouldn't expect his definition to work well outside of convex spaces.  The requirement means:  for any x and y, there is a z with d(x,z) + d(z,y) = d(x,z).

Comment: I don't get how it could not be well-defined. Do you mean *finite*? Or in the definition, do you mean that a basis should be minimal *with respect with inclusion*? Defining as you do bases as having minimal *cardinality* implies that they all have the same cardinal!

Comment: @MattF. This seems like it might be a crucial observation -- while connected graphs aren't convex metric spaces, they are "almost" convex in the sense that the convexity condition is satisfied for any two vertices which are not neighbors.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner If I'm being honest, I don't quite know what exactly cardinality means or what cardinals are. I thought that two sets have the same cardinality if and only if they belong to the same equivalence class/are isomorphic in the category Set, i.e. there exists a bijection between the two. Then finite sets with different numbers of elements would have different cardinalities. In the case of finite sets this should be the same thing as minimality with respect to inclusion, for infinite sets not necessarily since bijections with proper subsets are possible in the infinite case.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Ultimately the issue is that I don't know all of the relevant definitions correctly. I mean the same minimality which occurs for basises in vector spaces or more general matroids (inclusion/cardinality/bijection -- I don't know which it is for sure). As for metric dimension possibly not being well-defined, see the examples in the accepted answer to my previous question. It is obviously more difficult for it to not be well-defined when the metric dimension is infinite, but when it is finite it seems possible to cook up counterexamples which are not extremely complicated.

Comment: The line "A metric generating set $B$ is called a metric basis if it has minimal cardinality." seems to be causing some confusion that would be cleared up by changing it to "A metric generating set $B$ is called a metric basis if it has minimal cardinality among all metric generating sets."

Comment: I vote to close as ""not research-level". Too much time was already consumed by a plain confusion on minimality, and enough information is available to answer the question in the Answers and comments.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I find this comment to be unnecessarily insulting and not an entirely accurate description of the situation. I confused "cardinality of minimal metric generating set" with "metric generating set minimal with respect to cardinality" - the post has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Know that this confusion has been cleared, the question makes sense. But you have to realize that youe mistake, however honest, caused much time spent on needless work for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: This answer takes the definition of a metric basis as an *inclusion-minimal* metric generating set. This definition is **non-standard**.  [Another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278025/94968) deals with the same topics but takes the standard view of metric bases as *cardinality-minimal* metric generating sets.

Let's define the *weak metric dimension* of a metric space to be the common size of all *inclusion-minimal* generating sets, if this common value exists.

First I'll characterize those finite metric spaces with well-defined weak metric dimension in terms of the purity of a related [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) and then briefly talk about how [matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) fit into the picture.

## Simplicial Complex Background

We will need some terminology for (abstract) [simplicial complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex). A *simplicial complex* on a set $S$ is a collection of subsets $\Delta$ of $S$ that is closed under taking subsets, that is, if $T \in \Delta$ and $T' \subseteq T$, then $T' \in \Delta$. The elements of $\Delta$ are called its *faces* and the inclusion-maximal faces are the *facets* of $\Delta$. The *rank* of a face $F$ is given by $r(F)=\#F$ and the *rank* of $\Delta$, denoted $r(\Delta)$, is the largest rank of a face in $\Delta$.

Note that for a general simplicial complex, the cardinality of two facets need not be equal. (Example: $([3], \{\emptyset, 1, 2, 3, 23\})$.)  However, if all facets do have the same cardinality the simplicial complex is called *pure*.

## A (nearly trivial) characterization

Let $(M,d)$ be a *finite* metric space and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the collection of all generating sets for $(M,d)$. Define the set

$$\Delta = \Delta(M,d) := \{M \setminus G~|~G \in \mathcal{G}\}.$$

Note that if $G' \supseteq G$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$ then $G' \in \mathcal{G}$. This impies that the set $\Delta$ is an abstract simplicial complex on $M$. The facets of $\Delta$ correspond to *inclusion-minimal* generating sets of $(M,d)$ by set complementation. So the metric dimension of the finite metric space $(M,d)$ is well-defined (using this nonstandard definition) if and only if the complex $\Delta(M,d)$ is pure. In this case, $\dim(M,d) = \#M - r(\Delta)$.

## Example

Now let me try to tie this into the discussion of Example 1 of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric/275771#275771) to the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric). In that example we have $M = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $d$ given by

$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 \text{ if } x,y \neq 0 \\ 2 + \frac{1}{y} \text{ if } x = 0. \end{cases}$$

One computes that the metric generating sets consist of all subsets of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ except for the empty set and the singletons $\{i\}$ where $i \in [3]$. So $\Delta(M,d)$ is the simplicial complex whose faces are arranged by containment in the following poset. So $\Delta(M,d)$ is not pure (it has three facets of rank two and a facet of rank three) and so the metric dimension (using this nonstandard definition) of $\Delta(M,d)$ is not well-defined.

[image: The face poset of $Delta(M,d)$]

Let us note that using the standard definition of metric dimension $(M,d)$ has metric dimension one since its only metric basis is $\{0\}$; see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278025/94968) to this post for more on the standard case.

## Matroids

For an arbitrary finite metric space $(M,d)$, the complex $\Delta(M,d)$ is a matroid (that is, its facets satisfy the basis exchange axiom for matroids) if and only if the "matroid dual" complex

$$\Delta^*(M,d) := \{H \subseteq G | G \text{ is inclusion-minimal in } \mathcal{G}\}$$

is a matroid. In this case the metric dimension of $(M,d)$ is just the rank of $\Delta^*(M,d)$.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of simple, connected graphs on $n$ and $g(n)$ be the number of such graphs such that the weak metric dimension on the natural metric space $M(G)$ is well-defined. Also, let $h(n)$ be the number of those graphs counted by $g(n)$ whose weak metric bases are matroidal. Then using some [Macaualay2 scripts](https://github.com/aarondall/MetricSpaces.m2) we have the following values.

```
n    = 1 2 3 4 5   6   7
f(n) = 1 1 2 6 21 112 853
g(n) = 1 1 2 5 17  69 437  
h(n) = 1 1 2 5 16  61 290
```

One should compare this table to the similar table in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278025/94968).

Comment: This is an insightful analysis of the situation overall, which explains the relevant theory quite well in the simplest case, hopefully allowing one to generalize further. Just to clarify, abstract simplicial compexes are the same thing as independence complexes/independence systems/structures, correct? There appears to be a mistake in the analysis of Example 1, namely $\mathcal{G}$ as given is _not_ correct -- only the two or three element subsets of $\{1 ,2 ,3 \}$ belong to $\mathcal{G}$, thus the metric dimension is _not_ well-defined in that case. Otherwise this is a really great analysis.

Comment: There was an error in Example 1 of the answer to the previous question. The matroid in question in that example is $U_{1,1}$ together with three loops. The fact that there are loops in this matroid was overlooked in the analysis on that post. So indeed, the metric dimension of that example exists, and is one.

Comment: How are $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ metric generating sets? I don't understand yet.

Comment: And yes, abstract simplicial complexes are sometimes called independence complexes, independence structures, etc. But when dealing with graphs and/or matroids one needs to be careful because the term _independence complex_ can refer to a number of specific abstract simplicial complexes.

Comment: None of those singleton sets are metric generating sets. But each of $\{0,i\}$ for $i \in [3]$ are because $\{0\}$ is.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: The statement "only the two or three element subsets of $[3]:=\{1,2,3\}$ belong to $\mathcal{G}$" is incorrect. No subset of $[3]$ belongs to $\mathcal{G}$ because the metric doesn't differentiate between elements  in $[3]$. On the other hand, since $\{0\} \in \mathcal{G}$, any superset of $\{0\}$ is also in $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: When you say $[3]$, you are referring to the set $\{1,2,3\}$, correct, and not $\{0, 1, 2,3\}$? (Otherwise I wouldn't understand your argument.) So your argument is to define basis in terms of independence systems, and not matroids? (How could this correspond to a matroid if it doesn't satisfy the exchange axiom -- to satisfy the exchange axiom $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ also need to be basises, right?) (Also, the metric does differentiate between elements of $\{1,2,3\}$: $d(0,1)= 1$ while $d(0,2) = \frac{3}{2}$ and $d(0,3) = \frac{5}{3}$.)

Comment: I think $\{1, 2\}$ is a basis, because $d(0,1) = 1, d(0,2) = \frac{3}{2}, d(3,1)=2, d(3,2)= 2$, but $d(1,1)=0,d(1,2)=2$ and $d(2,1)=2, d(2,2)=0$, so $3$ is differentiated from $1$ and $2$, and of course $3 = 3$. But I am being a little sloppy so I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for explicit calculation! I was the one being sloppy so I just wrote a little code for computing with finite metric spaces in [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) to help me clear up my confusion. Using it on this example shows me where my error is. The set $G$ consists of all subsets of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ except the empty set and the singletons in $[3] := \{1,2,3\}$. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is completely unrelated, but Macaulay2 does stuff with matroids and simplicial complexes? That is both really cool and something I did not know.

Comment: The `SimplicialComplexes` package has been around since 2006. Justin Chen wrote the [Matroids](https://github.com/jchen419/Matroids-M2) package more recently. And last year I wrote the [MatroidActivities](https://github.com/aarondall/MatroidActivities-M2) package for studying ordered matroids. Please use them and let me know what you think!

Comment: @Chill2Macht: I'm not sure on the etiquette around here, but I'd just as well delete this answer as (1) it is fatally flawed and (2) my new answer fixes all the problems that this one has. Do you object? If so, I can also edit the answer to highlight the errors and point users who come to this page to the new answer.

Comment: I guess you can delete it, although I thought it would have made more sense to just edit it until it was correct, than to post a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Metric dimension is well-defined

The usual definition of metric dimension (and the one initially given in the OP) is the smallest cardinality of any metric basis. This generalizes the notion for [metric dimension in graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_dimension_(graph_theory)) and is well-defined for any metric space (finite or not).

To see this let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{G}$ be the collection of metric generating sets. There are two natural posets one can define on $\mathcal{G}$: let $P_1 = (\mathcal{G}, |\cdot|)$ be defined by $G \prec G'$ if $|G| < |G'|$ and let $P_2 = (\mathcal{G}, \subset)$ be defined by $G \prec G'$ if $G \subset G'$. Note that the minimal elements of $P_1$ are the metric bases $\mathcal{B}(M,d)$. Also notice that the metric bases are  contained in the minimal elements of $P_2$ and that this containment is generally strict.

## Metric Bases and Matroids

Fix a metric space $(M,d)$ where $M$ is a *finite* set. Let $r$ be the metric dimension of $(M,d)$. Since the metric bases $\mathcal{B}(M,d)$ of $(M,d)$ all have the same cardinality one can ask if and when $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of bases of a [matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid).

Recall that a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of (finite) sets is the set of bases of a matroid if it satisfies the following exchange axiom: for every $B,B' \in \mathcal{B}$ and every $e \in B$ there is some $f \in B'$ such that the set $B \setminus \{e\} \cup \{f\}$ is also in $B$.

First let's see that there are some finite metric spaces whose metric bases are the bases of a matroid. Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected connected graph and let $d: V \times V \to \mathbb{N}$ be the map that takes a pair of vertices to the length of the shortest path between them. Then $M(G) := (V,d)$ is a metric space. A simple computation shows the following fact.

**Fact**: Let $G = (V,E)$ be a simple connected graph with $|V| \le 4$. Then the metric bases of $M(G)$ are the bases of a matroid.

This fact does not extend to all graphs with $|V|=5$. To see this consider the graph $G = ([5], \{13,14,15,24,25,35\})$. Then $M(G)$ has 22 metric generating sets and six metric bases

$$\mathcal{B}(M(G)) = \{12, 15, 23, 24, 25, 34\}.$$

Notice that for $B = 12$, $e = 2$, and $B'= 34$ there is no element $f \in B'$ such that $B \setminus 2 \cup f$ is also a metric basis. So the metric bases of $M(G)$ are not the bases of any matroid.

This graph is unique among simple connected graphs on five vertices in that it is the only one whose metric bases are not matroidal. Let $f(n)$ be the number of the simple connected graphs on $n$ vertices and let $g(n)$ be the number of such graphs whose metric bases are *not* matroidal. We used [these Macaulay2 scripts](https://github.com/aarondall/MetricSpaces.m2/blob/master/README.md) to compute $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for $n \le 7$.

```
n    = 1 2 3 4  5  6   7
f(n) = 1 1 2 6 21 112 853
g(n) = 0 0 0 0  1  18 323
```

More on when the metric bases of a graph are matroidal can be found in these two papers: [BC2011](http://www2.grenfell.mun.ca/rbailey/papers/basesize_metdim.pdf) and [B2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.1427.pdf).

## Another example

Finally let's return to Example 1 of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric/275771#275771) to the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric). In that example we have $M = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $d$ given by

$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 \text{ if } x,y \neq 0 \\ 2 + \frac{1}{y} \text{ if } x = 0. \end{cases}$$

The metric generating sets of $(M,d)$ consist of all subsets of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ other than the singletons $\{i\}$, where $i \in \{1,2,3\}$. In particular, $\{0\}$ is a metric generating set of cardinality one. So the metric dimension of $(M,d)$ is one and $\{0\}$ is the only metric basis. It follows that the set of metric bases $\mathcal{B}(M,d)$ is matroidal with the corresponding matroid on four elements being isomorphic to the uniform matroid $U_{1,1}$ together with three loops.

Comment: I'm still confused (I'm sorry, I'm not very smart) -- how is the metric dimension well defined in the last example? $\{0\}$ is a metric generating set of cardinality one, and minimal -- but $\{1,2\}$ is also a metric generating set, but also minimal, since $\{1\}, \{2\}, \emptyset$ aren't metric generating sets, and $\{0\} \not\subset \{1, 2\}$, but the cardinality of $\{1,2\}$ is two -- so we have one metric basis with cardinality one, and one metric basis with cardinality two, so isn't the metric dimension not well-defined? We could change the definition to minimum, and then it would work.

Comment: I really appreciate all of the work you are putting into answering my question- I wouldn't understand the problem nearly as well without your input. It is really insightful and a perspective I would not have been able to acquire on my own.I am just confused about whether it makes more sense to change the definition to minimum cardinality among metric generating sets from minimal cardinality among metric generating sets.For vector spaces one can use minimal cardinality,and for Euclidean spaces one can use minimal metric generating set,so I want to generalize that,but maybe it isn't a good idea.

Comment: The fact that metric dimension is well-defined hinges on the definition that metric bases are metric generating sets of minimal cardinality (and not just inclusion minimal generating sets). In the above example the set containing 1 and 2 is inclusion minimal but is not minimal with respect to cardinality, so it is not a metric basis.

Comment: The definition of metric dimension you give above (with metric bases defined as cardinality-minimal generating sets) does generalize the definition of metric dimension for vector spaces and (affine) Euclidean spaces.

Comment: How is it not minimal with respect to cardinality? It contains no metric generating sets of smaller cardinality. Is that not what minimal means?

Comment: @Chill2Macht: "minimal with respect to cardinality" is the notion you seem not to have understood, provoking your question and some confusion. Please *read carefully* the paragraph of "Metric dimension is well defined" of this answer, it gives a clear, short and precise definition. "Minimal with respect to cardinality" has nothing to do with inclusion. In the example $\{1,2\}$ has cardinality $2$, which is more than $1=\#\{0\}$, thus is not minimal  with respect to cardinality (among metric generating sets of course).

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my contribution to your brainstorming.

Let $\ (X\ d)\ $ be a metric space. Then it is isometric to the image under the Kuratowski-Wojdysławski embedding
    $\ \imath : X\rightarrow \mbox{Met}(X\ d) \ $
(where $\ \mbox{Met}(X\ d) \ $ is the set of all real metric maps
    $\ f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ on
    $\ (X\ d)\ $ such that uniform distance between
    $\ f\ $ and $\ \imath(x)\ $ is finite).

> **REMARK 1:** The uniform distance between $\ f\ $ as above
>   and $\ \imath(x)\ $ is either finite for all $\ x\in X,\ $ or
>   it is infinite for all $\ x\in X$.
>
> **REMARK 2:** When the diameter of $\ (X\ d)\ $ is finite then
>   $\ \mbox{Met}(X\ d) = \mbox{Lip}_1(X\ d)$.

Then there is more then one way to follow from here.
I would choose the following one:

**DEFINITION** The metric dimension of $\ (X\ d)\ $ is the smallest topological dimension of any topological manifold
     $\ M\subseteq \mbox{Met}(X\ d)\ $
such that $\ \imath(X)\subseteq M$.

This means that metrics/topology of $\ M\ $ is inherited from

$$ \mbox{Met}(X\ d)\ \subseteq \mbox{Lip}_1(X\ d) $$

and $\ M\ $ under such metrics/topology is a topological manifold.

> 

**THEOREM** If a metric space $\ (M^n\ d)\ $ is a topological $n$-dimensional manifold then the metric dimension of $\ (M^n\ d)\ $ is the topological dimension of $\ (M^n\ d)\ $, is $\ n$.

> **Kuratowski-Wojdysławski embedding:**
>
> $$ \imath : X\rightarrow
> \mbox{Met}(X)\subseteq\mbox{Lip}_1(X)\subseteq C(X) $$
>
> is defined by:
>   $$ \forall_{x\ y\in X}\ (\imath(x))(y)\ :=\ d(x\ y) $$

Comment: This does not answer the question. Your seem to propose a different definition of metric dimension, while the question is about a certain given definition.