# Almost Lipschitz embedding of compact metric measure spaces into Euclidean spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces, embeddings, metric-embeddings

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, $m$ be a metric outer-measure on $X$.  Are there 'mild conditions' on $X$ ensuring the existence of a positive integer $N\geq 3$ such that *there exist $x_1,\dots,x_N\in X$ satisfying*
$$
m\big(\big\{
x\in X:\, \exists x_0\in X-\{x\}\; (\forall i=1,\dots,N)\quad d(x,x_i)=d(x_0,x_i)
\big\}\big)=0.
$$
In other words, the Kuraotwski-esque map $X\ni x\mapsto (d(x,x_n))_{n=1}^N\in \mathbb{R}^N$ is injective outside a set of metric outer-measure $0$.

---

*Note*:  If $N$ were to be infinite, then the above embedding is the usual embedding of $X$ into the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\omega}$, which is known to be an *isometry*.  So I would expect that, the set of 'bad points' asymptotically vanishes.

Comment: This question may be relevant to you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275493/when-does-a-metric-space-have-infinite-metric-dimension-definition-of-metric/275507 Most of the answers consist of simple examples in which one cannot find such a map on the whole space X. Of course, this doesn't answer your question, but it gives some terminology that might help.

Comment: @user142382  Thank you, I will take a look.  I also note that I added some intuition.